# The API call with RXJS is not working properly

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have component and service. The component is calling to service function which is creating API call.
Once the API call is completed I want to call to another function and pass the result of api call.
The technologies: angular, rxjs, swagger

In component:

```
of(this.customerService.getCustomerOverview(this.id)).subscribe((x)=>{
      console.log(x);
      this.getResultValues(x);
    });
```

In service:

```
getCustomerOverview(id) {
    this.localSubscriptions.push(this.apiClient.getCustomer(id, '').subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    },
      (error: any) => {

      }));
  }
```

The error:
The this.getResultValues(x); is called before the API call is completed and the result is back to the calling function.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Angular has a built in http client that returns an observable. I reccomemd taking a look at their examples as the way you are doing this is way more complex than it should be. https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Really this is just a matter of you can’t return from inside a subscribe. Remove the subscribe and return an observable instead. Then you can also remove that of(). Just remember you can’t return from a subscribe, just you could really return from a node classic callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would do:

```
// service
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
....
public customerCache$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
getCustomerOverview(id) {
  return this.apiClient.getCustomer(id, '');
}
.....
// component
import { of } from 'rxjs;
import { switchMap, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
.....
this.customerService.customerCache$.pipe(
  // take(1) to kill the subscription after the subscribe, I am scared of an infinite loop because of the .next in the subscribe
  take(1),
  switchMap(cache => {
     // if the cache is truthy, great, use it
     if (cache) {
       return of(cache);
     } else {
       // else make an API call
       return this.customerService.getCustomerOverview(this.id);
     }
  }),
).subscribe(x => {
  // store x as the cache
  this.customerService.customerCache$.next(x);
  // make sure this console doesn't log infinitely
  console.log(x);
  this.getResultValues(x);
});
```

There is no need to unsubscribe from `http` calls in Angular since they are finite.

Now everywhere else you need to read the value from, you can read it from the cache similarly to this. I am not a fan of this because I would use Ngrx. Continuing this way creates spaghetti code.

Comment: Thanks AliF50. It is a scenario I have used before. A problem with this scenario is that if I want to call the result of that API second time. Let's say I have called the API first time and assigned the data to variable getCustomerOverview(id) {
    if(!this.customerOverview){
      this.customerOverview=this.apiClient.getCustomer(id, '');
    }
    return this.customerOverview;
  } my variable is an observable and anyway it create an API call. How would you resolve that?

Comment: You want to not call the service if you have already made a call to it?

Comment: I want to call the service but if the data is existing not to call the API second time. However, my variable is observable and the API is called anyway. I see it in Network

Comment: Can you not do it with an `if` statement? Check out my edit.

Comment: It is working. Good solution! Thanks. However interesting if there is an Rxjs solution for that issue, i.e. calling the service and return observable without calling API. Your solution, however, good working version.

Comment: It won't work if I call this service from different components. Let's say you called first time from one component. Then you want to call from another component and not to do an API call. But in the second component, you don't have a variable with the value

Comment: Yes, this calls for `Ngrx`/Redux which is a database for your frontend application. https://ngrx.io/. But I will show you a way to do how you want it.

Comment: Check out my edit, I recommend using `Ngrx`. Will take a while to learn but you can make much better applications.